# How to remove line break<br> from and mysql output using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I used

```
 <br>
```

in textarea to write some articles in backend, the output came exactly what i expected on webpage.I used 3rd party apps to share the article description to mobiles and in social netowrking. While sharing the article description the br> tags are seen in the 3rd party apps.

How to remove the 
 tags from the article description ?

```
<?php echo ($rows['description']); ?>
```

I used the below method which removes the 
tag but it also removes the line breaks in the artile. How to remove the 
tag and not line break in textarea

```
<?php
$value=$rows['description'];
$sendarticle= preg_replace('/[\<br>]/', '', $value);
?>
```

Comment: Have you already tried a simple `str_replace`?

Comment: Simple `str_replace` will do the job, else you can try `strip_tags()` too

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's

[`strip_tags($str)`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php)

function to replace all NULL-Bytes, PHP-Tags and HTML-tags from `$str`.

Comment: it remove the br tag and also the line break

Comment: `strip_tags` doesn't remove any carriage returns or line feeds.

Comment: it removes <br>tag and also removes line break.After removing line break article has no paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo htmlentities($rows['description']); ?>
```

try this